# How can I make components from the native base responsive on various screens

Tags: react-native, native-base

How can I make components from the native base responsive on various screens?
I tested on several different cellphone screens, but the native base was unresponsive,
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**React Native provides a `Dimensions` module** if you want to retrieve the device's exact window height or width. Here is an example for a fullscreen View:

```js
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

<View style={{
     width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
     height: Dimensions.get('window').height
}}></View>
```

Furthermore, React Native styling supports **Flexbox** (more or less like CSS). You can lean more about it in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox).